# How to Customize my blocking page with content blocker swift

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, safari-content-blocker

I'm working with **Content Blocker** in Swift 3 and everything is working perfectly, but now I want to change my block page when a url is blocked through content blocker.

[image]

As you can see in the image, my blocking page is so simple and I want to show an image with a message.

**Is there a way to do that with Content Blocker in Swift 3?**